# How do I sort a list with "Nones last"

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm sorting a list of dicts by a key:

```
groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda a: a['name'])
```

some of the dicts have name set to `None`, and Python 2 places `None` values before any other, so they're placed at the front of the sorted list. A naive fix would be

```
groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda a: a['name'] or 'zzzz')
```

but, obviously, that would not work for any non-Latin names.

What is a nice and Pythonic way of sorting a list containing `None` values so that those  values are placed at the end of the list?

Comment: FWIW, using a list of a custom class you create, would make this trivial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by keying it on a tuple:

```
groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda a: (a['name'] is None, a['name']))
```

---

This works because Python compares tuples lexicographically (on the first element, then on the second to break ties), and because False gets sorted earlier than True. A list of groups like

```
[{'name': 0}, {'name': 1}, {'name': 2}, {'name': 3}, {'name': 4}, {'name': None}]
```

will become

```
[(False, 0), (False, 1), (False, 2), (False, 3), (False, 4), (True, None)]
```

The tuple that starts with `True` will necessarily end up at the end, and the rest, since the first value ties, will be sorted by the second value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the official docs explains this somewhere. Even if it doesn't, this is still the one obvious way to do it, it's just not quite as obvious. :)

Comment: That's very clever indeed, thanks :) Although a 10-character change in the code required 4 lines of comments to explain how the thing works :))

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own "infinity" object:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Infinity:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) == Infinity
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False
```

Use it like so:

```
>>> lis = [{'name': 1}, {'name': None}, {'name': 0}, {'name': 2}]
>>> sorted(lis, key=lambda a: Infinity() if a['name'] is None else a['name'])
[{'name': 0}, {'name': 1}, {'name': 2}, {'name': None}]
```

Comment: That's a nice solution too although maybe a bit overkill for my use case

Comment: Potentially a bit more efficient than the tuple solution though: the keys are smaller, and the (probably) common case of comparing two non-None names does an extra comparison with the tuples. Marginal difference though, style is more important. And personally I would call this one of the very few cases where a Singleton is justified.